# Finding all possible combinations of elements in a list of integers. all elements of any of the new list have to be at least 2 apart

Tags: python, list, combinations

I need a function that gets a list as an input and returns all the combinations with the maximum amount of integers used (here 5) which don't have 2 adjacent integers like 2, 3 or 6,7.

```
list0 = [0, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13]

all_combinations = magic_function(list0)
```

all_combinations would be this:

```
[[0, 3, 6, 10, 12],
 [0, 3, 6, 11, 13],
 [0, 4, 6, 10, 12],
 [0, 4, 6, 11, 13]]
```

It could be done by getting all combinations and then picking out the correct ones, but I can't have it use much memory or be slow, because it has to work with lists with length up to 98 elements.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: This is actually an interesting problem.

Comment: I think you're missing a couple valid outputs: `[0, 3, 6, 10, 13], [0, 4, 6, 10, 13]`

Comment: `np.diff` and `itertools.permutations` will get the job done...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def combos(d, c = []):
   if len(c) == 5:
      yield c
   else:
      for i in d:
         if not c or c[-1]+1 < i:
            yield from combos(d, c+[i])

list0 = [0, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13]
print(list(combos(list0)))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3, 6, 10, 12], 
 [0, 3, 6, 10, 13], 
 [0, 3, 6, 11, 13], 
 [0, 4, 6, 10, 12], 
 [0, 4, 6, 10, 13], 
 [0, 4, 6, 11, 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is as follows:

```py
import itertools

lst = [0, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13] # 0 | 3 4 | 6 | 10 11 12 13

chunks, chunk = [], [] # defining chunk here is actually useless
prev = None
for x in lst:
    if prev is None or x - prev > 1: # if jump > 1
        chunks.append(chunk := []) # insert a brand-new chunk
    chunk.append(x)
    prev = x # update the previous number

def max_nonadjacents(chunk): # maximal nonadjacent sublists (given a chunk)
    if not chunk or len(chunk) % 2: # odd length is easy
        return {tuple(chunk[::2])}
    return{tuple((chunk[:i] + chunk[i+1:])[::2]) for i in range(len(chunk))}

output = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(prod)) # flattening
              for prod in itertools.product(*map(max_nonadjacents, chunks))]

print(output)
# [[0, 3, 6, 11, 13], [0, 3, 6, 10, 12], [0, 3, 6, 10, 13], [0, 4, 6, 11, 13], [0, 4, 6, 10, 12], [0, 4, 6, 10, 13]]
```

I am assuming that the input list is sorted.

Basically, my approach starts with recognizing that the problem can be divided into smaller pieces; the list can be divided into chunks, where each chunk comprises of running integers; `[0]`, `[3, 4]`, `[6]`, `[10, 11, 12, 13]`.

Then you can see you can get all the possible combinations by taking all the maximal non-adjacent lists from each chunk, and then taking the products of the lists across the chunks.

The code follows this procedure: (i) get the `chunks`, (ii) define a helper function `max_nonadjacents` that extracts all the maximal non-adjacent lists, (iii) apply it to each chunk (`map(max_nonadjacents, ...)`), and then (iv) take the products.